# Find all locations $geoWithin $geoIntersects

Tags: mongodb

I want to find out which Polygon from a collection, contains the most points from another collection.

I’m using one collection with restaurant data (points) and one with the neighborhood data (polygons)

Both collections are provided by mongodb:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mongodb/docs-assets/geospatial/neighborhoods.json
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mongodb/docs-assets/geospatial/restaurants.json

Neighborhood document:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "55cb9c666c522cafdb053a1a"
    },
    "geometry": {
        "coordinates": [
            [
                [
                    -73.9443878859649,
                    40.70042452378256
                ],
                [
                    -73.94424286147482,
                    40.69969927964773
                ], 
[
                    -73.94193078816193,
                    40.70072523469547
                ],…
            ]
        ],
        "type": "Polygon"
    },
    "name": "Bedford"
}
```

Restaurant document

```
{
"_id" : { "$oid" : "55cba2476c522cafdb053add" },
"location" : {"coordinates":[-73.856077,40.848447] , "type":"Point" },
"name" : "Morris Park Bake Shop"
}
```

Here an example to find out all restaurants within a single district:

Select one neighborhood (polygon) by a given point ($geoIntersects)

```
var neighborhood = db.neighborhoods.findOne( 
{ 
    geometry: 
    { 
     $geoIntersects: 
     { 
      $geometry: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ -73.93414657, 40.82302903 ] } 
     } 
    } 
} 
)
```

Find out how many restaurants are in this neighborhood

```
db.restaurants.find( { location: { $geoWithin: { $geometry: neighborhood.geometry } } } ).count()
```

My question:

Which neighborhood contains the most restaurants?